# Re-order vector row-wise from top of vector

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector (`x`) whose values are in such an order that if they were in an `nx` by `ny` matrix, the matrix would contain values that increase by row starting from the bottom left upwards.  Any remaining unfilled values in the matrix will then be `NA`.  Let me illustrate with an example:

```
nr=3
nc=3    
mx = matrix(c(7,NA,NA,4:6,1:3), nr, nc, byrow = T)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    7   NA   NA
# [2,]    4    5    6
# [3,]    1    2    3
x = c(mx)
# [1]  7  4  1 NA  5  2 NA  6  3
```

Now, I would like to re-order x into a new vector (`y`) such that if the values of `y` were in a matrix the `NA`s would remain in the same location, but the other values would be ordered increasing row-wise from the *top* left.  I.e. `y` should look like this

```
my = matrix(c(1,NA,NA,2:4,5:7), nr, nc, byrow = T)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1   NA   NA
# [2,]    2    3    4
# [3,]    5    6    7
y = c(y)
# [1]  1  2  5 NA  3  6 NA  4  7
```

I want to find a vector of indices that maps x to y. In this case it would be

```
indices = c(3, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7, 2, 1)
identical(x[indices], y)
#TRUE
```

But, I'm struggling to find a simple algorithm that can generate `indices` for any values of `nr`, `nc`, and any number of NA values in `x`.  Any suggestions?  NB, we can assume that there will never be enough `NA`s to fill an entire matrix row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my = t(replace(t(mx), which(!is.na(t(mx))), sort(mx)))
my
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1   NA   NA
#[2,]    2    3    4
#[3,]    5    6    7
match(my, mx)
#[1] 3 6 5 4 9 8 4 2 1
```

Or, if the indices vector must have a one-to-one correspondence between the two vectors, such that it does not point to the same NA twice:

```
match(replace(my, is.na(my), paste0("NA", seq(sum(is.na(my))))),
      replace(mx, is.na(mx), paste0("NA", seq(sum(is.na(mx))))))
#[1] 3 6 5 4 9 8 7 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `apply` rowwise, and then transpose, you get back the original matrix arrangement. The function given to apoply replaces non-NA values with ordered non-NA values and then returns the full row..

```
t( apply(mx, 1, function(x){ x[!is.na(x)] <- x[!is.na(x)][order(x[!is.na(x)])]; x}) )
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    7   NA   NA
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    1    2    3
```

If you wanted the values without the matrix arrangement just unclass or wrap it in `c`. If you want the order vector then you could first set a y value inside the function that is 1:length(x) and then assign the !is.na ordering.